# UIDatePicker iOS 14 compact style remove default background

Tags: ios, swift, uidatepicker

I have a native UIDatePicker in my app that is showing date only and I set its style to compact. I can see rounded background under date.

In the view hierarchy I see:

UIDatePicker - UIDatePickerIOSCompactView - UIView - UIView, _UIDatePickerLinkedLabel

Both of the last subviews have grey background color. When I call subviews on my picker, it returns an empty array even though in the hierarchy I see bunch.

So I'm curious if it's possible to remove or change the native background color somehow?

Any kind of help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This removes the gray background for me on a compact style date picker:

```
datePicker.subviews[0].subviews[0].subviews[0].alpha = 0
```